# Saving form data on a swipe rather than from a button click in Android

Tags: android-viewpager, fragment, swipe

I am new in android and I just want to build the app that have questions in multiple fragment and each fragment must swipe only after answering the current.If user try to swipe than he should be alert to answer the question.
My requirement is just like as in the link : [Collecting Data with KoBoCollect on Android](http://%20https://support.kobotoolbox.org/kobocollect-android.html)